# Kubernetes Hostalias redirecting to Kubernetes service without Request Headers

Tags: docker, redirect, kubernetes, hosts

Running this in MINIKUBE before I push to AWS

I am trying a "Man in the middle" on one of my pods. 
Idea, change the hosts file inside my docker container that lives inside a kubernetes pod. The hosts file will see a request to api.app.org and redirect any calls to this host to ip address "10.101.63.179". The application running on the kubernetes service is an express app that captures http requests and directs them to the appropriate method for consumption. 
The app looks at the request headers and breaks out the "host" and the "URL".
Should look like this

host = api.app.org

URL = "/v2/1234"

Expected : 
The kubernetes service will be sent an HTTP request.
example : api.app.org/v2/1234
Node Express app is called and manages execution based on "host" and the rest of the URL. "/v2/1234"

Actual:
1. HOSTS file is updated via Kubernetes hostalias added inside the deployment. Code below.
2. Call from within application makes an HTTP request to "api.app.org/v2/1234" .
3. The HOSTS file redirects the HTTP request to IP address "10.101.63.179"
-- so far so good --

(inside express app now) .

1. Runs a method to extract Host and the rest of the URL.
   -- example : host should equal ( api.app.org )
   -- example : url should equal (/v2/1234) .

PROBLEM...

host =  10.101.63.179 .

URL = / .

---

CODE : /etc/hosts . 
host file from docker image inside kubernetes pod : ran (kubectl exec -it  -c  -- /bin/bash ) .

`# Entries added by HostAliases.
10.101.63.179   api.stats.com
10.101.63.179   api.ap.org`

---

CODE: Kubernetes Deployment YAML

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: testharness
  labels:
    run: raven-svc
  name: raven-svc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: raven-svc
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: raven-svc
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: raven-svc
        image: raven:vFin
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
      hostAliases:
        - ip: "10.101.63.179"
          hostnames:
          - "api.stats.com"
          - "api.ap.org"
      restartPolicy: Always`

Answer (score 1):

The hosts file as basically at IP level in the stack so it wouldn't strip any layer 6-7 headers(http/https). Also kubernetes sets up iptables to route between pods and generally that's all at the IP level too.

Is `10.101.63.179` an ingress controller by any chance? that could be stripping your headers.

Comment: You maybe onto something. I do have an ingress that uses that service.
I wonder if I create a whole new deployment along with a service. 
I will update the comment when I have something.

Comment: Still a no go. 
Create a whole new deployment and service (clusterIP) . 
Then ssh into docker container inside the POD and ran ```curl 10.98.167.224;```... I got back the service home page.  
I then ran my test and the headers are stripped out or never made it.

Comment: Did you try `curl -vvv -H 'Header1: value1' -H 'Header2: value2' 10.98.167.224`. You are saying that inside the pod to the IP address of the pod/container and the headers are getting stripped? (not going through the ingress)

Comment: curl -vvv -H 'x-testharness-host : api.app.com' 10.98.167.224 
  
Yep, that went through...   
Very odd . 
Wonder if it is a MINIKUBE thing

Comment: I was reading about Kubernetes hostAliases.
It was speaking about "POD Level"... I am going to put my service docker container and my App docker container into one Kubernetes POD and see if that fixes the problem .

Comment: Nevermind... forgot that all containers within a POD share the same IP but run on different ports

Comment: Happens on AWS as well.. so not a Minikube thing.

Comment: Ok l, further reading. Seems I will have to use an NGINX as a reverse proxy. I am going to try to load this as a sidecar to capture traffic from one running docker container

Comment: haha ok.. this did not work.
Lack of knowledge ... maybe. 
Moving onto linkerd now. 
https://linkerd.io/1/features/transparent-proxying/